# Why does Ruby's each_with_object drop data that was appended with the += operator to the array memo?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm stumped by the following Ruby behaviour:

```
result = [1,2,3].each_with_object([]) do |elem, memo|
  memo << [elem]
end
puts result.to_s
# => [[1], [2], [3]]
```

The above code works how I would expect it to work. However, the code below just seems to drop the numbers I'm trying to append to the array.

```
result = [1,2,3].each_with_object([]) do |elem, memo|
  memo += [elem]
end
puts result.to_s
# => []
```

Could anyone explain to me what's going on here and how I am supposed to use the `+=` operator with `each_with_object` in the above context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

memo is local variable, that points to an array object. these loop variables are set at each iteration.

In the first example, you change this array object.

In the second example, you override the local variable with a new array. Because `memo += [elem]` is just a shorthand for `memo = momo + [elem]`
The old array stays empty.

Very often you better use `inject` instead of `each_with_object`. With inject, the new memo variable is set with the result of the block, so you can use non-destructive functions.

```
[1,2,3].inject([]) do |memo, elem| 
  memo + [elem]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

According to docs, `+=` – concatenation – returns a new array built by concatenating the two arrays together to produce a third array.

Thus, on every iteration the block result is set to a new array, that is reset back to the empty array that you've passed to `each_with_object` method in the next iteration. Consider the following [**demonstration**](https://repl.it/BviH).